# GitHub automatic label assignment on action

Tags: git, github, label, transition, issue-tracking

In GitHub we are using issues. For tracking issues progress and current state we are using labels. More precisely we are using so to speak label groups. So for our tracking we are using following labels:

- `status:todo`
- `status:in_progress`
- `status:code_review`
- `status:done`

We would like to automate that transitions as much as we can. From `todo` to `in_progress` a trigger is creating remote branch (with an issue number in the name somehow). Trigger from `in_progress` to `code_review` is when PR is opened. And after the issue is close the status should be `done`.

We have all triggers well defined and they are known to GH. We read a lot of docs and blog posts but was not able to find such instructions if this is possible (and how) or not.

Some help here would be more than awesome!

Thanks!